# problem in fetching a particular cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is the script that i am using to fetch a particular cookie `lastvisit` :

**AFTER THE EDIT**

```
// This document writes a cookie
// called from index.php
window.onload = makeLastVisitCookie;

function makeLastVisitCookie() {
var now = new Date();
var last = new Date();
now.setFullYear(2020);
// set the cookie
document.cookie = "lastvisit=" + last.toDateString() + ";path=/;expires=" + now.toGMTString();
var allCookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for( var i=0 ; i < allCookies.length ; i++ ) {
    if(allCookies[i].split("=")[0]== "lastvisit") {
        document.getElementById("last_visit").innerHTML = "You visited this site on" + allCookies[i].split("=")[1];
    } else {
                alert("testing..testing..");
              }
  }
 }
```

From this script the `if` part never works though there are 5 cookies stored from my website. *(including the cookie that i am saving from this script)* What is the mistake that i am making while fetching the cookie named `lastvisit` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're splitting the cookie by `;` an comparing those tokens with `lastvisit`. You need to split such a token by `=` first. `allCookies[i]` looks like `key=val` and will never equal `lastvisit`. Een if `allCookies[i] == "lastvisit"` is true, the result will still not be as expected since you're showing the value of `allCookies[i + 1]` which would be `this=the_cookie_after_lastvisit`.

`if(allCookies[i].split("=") == "lastvisit") {` should be:

```
var pair = allCookies[i].split("=", 2);
if (pair[0].replace(/^ +/, "") == "lastvisit") {
```

`"You visited this site on" + allCookies[i+1];` should be:

```
"You visited this site on" + pair[1];
```

The `2` argument of `split` makes cookies like `sum=1+1=2` be read correctly. When splitting cookies by `;`, the key may contain a leading space which much be removed before comparing. (`/^ +/` is a regular expression where `^` matches the beginning of a string and `+` one or more spaces.)

Alternatively, compare it directly against a RE for matching the optional spaces as well (`*` matches zero or more occurences of a space character, `$` matches the end of a string):

```
if (/^ *lastvisit$/.test(pair[0])) {
```

I've tested several ways to get a cookie including using regular expressions and the below was the most correct one with best performance:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookie = "; " + document.cookie + ";";
    var search = "; " + encodeURIComponent(name) + "=";
    var value_start = cookie.indexOf(search);
    if (value_start == -1) return "";
    value_start += search.length;
    var value_end = cookie.indexOf(';', value_start);
    return decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(value_start, value_end))
}
```

Comment: please see the edit. After splitting in the if statement things remain unchanged

Comment: I've once again edited the condition of `if` and the statement inside the `if` block. But that does not work . Can you please tell what is the problem.Now i have broken the token from `=`

Comment: @ Lekensteyn Thank you for the edit,but can you please point what is the problem with my code (after the last edit) . And what does `/^ +/` mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove possible white space around the cookie key before comparing to the string `"lastvisit"`. This is done conveniently using regular expressions. `/^\s+/` matches all white space at the beginning, `/\s+$/` matches all white space at the end. The matches are replaced by the empty string, i.e. removed:

```
for( var i = 0 ; i < allCookies.length ; i++ ) {
    var c = allCookies[i].split("="); // split only once
    var key = c[0].replace(/^\s+/, '').replace (/\s+$/, ''); // remove blanks around key
    if (key == "lastvisit") {
        document.getElementById("last_visit").innerHTML = "You visited on " + c[1];
    }
    //...
}
```